error: package io.realm does not exist import io.realm.Realm;
error: package io.realm does not exist
import io.realm.Realm;error: package io.realm does not exist
This is my project level build.gradle.kts
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
  //  id("realm-android") apply false
}

This is my moudle level build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)


}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.notes"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.notes"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.support.annotations)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    //classpath('io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.1')
   // implementation("io.realm:realm-android-library:10.11.1") // Add the Realm dependency
    annotationProcessor(libs.realm.realm.android)
   // implementation("")
}

This is my Settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Notes"
include(":app")
 

this is my libs.versions.toml
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Notes"
include(":app")



I spent many hours to solve this issue please help me to solve it
Thanks
I tried mavenCentral() and jCenter in my settings.gradle.kts but failed I tried different plugins but failed

Welcome to SO. The question is a bit unclear. I see the error but did you go through the Getting Started guides to set up your environment? It also seems like that's some older outdated code from 7-8 years ago. Check the guide!

not older, I recently installed the latest version of Android Studio
